# Why no constructor() in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React native, while going through the docs I found that in React Native the components are written without implementing the `constructor()` function and the states are declared directly in the class. I wonder why that is, as opposed to states being declared inside the constructor like in React.

example from React Native doc:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

class Cat extends Component {
  state = { isHungry: true };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        ...
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. It's just a preference of the author of these examples.

Comment: If I don't use the constructor() declaration, how would I bind methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, both ways are valid if you are using Babel, and [this article](https://hackernoon.com/the-constructor-is-dead-long-live-the-constructor-c10871bea599) explains it well!